# How to set an image as a footer in a mobile application with flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I'm working on a mobile App with Flutter.

I've got a Scaffold which has in its body a ListView of widgets. I'd like to set an image at the bottom of the screen as last element of the ListView.

```
return Scaffold(
backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF8F8F8),
appBar: myAppBar,
body: ListView(
children: <Widget>[
    //some widgets,
    Container(
      child:Image.asset(_bottomImageLocation),
    ),
  ],
  ),
bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar,
);
```

_bottomImageLocation contains the path of the asset.
I've got a problem when the ListView is smaller than the screen, in that case the image is not at the bottom of the screen. I would like to "expand" the listView if it doesn't fill entirely the screen, so that I could obtain the desired effect (the image at the bottom).

Do you think it could be possible?
In which way?

The effect that I want:

[image]

The effect that I get:

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Can you please add any images related to your problem statement ?

Comment: Do you want the image to stick to the bottom? Lets say we have 10 elements(11 element is image), you want to display the image only after scrolling?

Comment: add an image about what you need

Comment: @DineshBalasubramaniane yes exactly!

Comment: edited with images